# Object as private member of a class

Tags: c++, object

I've a class called `Socket`, with two constructors:

```
Socket(int port){...} 
Socket(string address, int port){...}
```

I'd like to use one instance of that Socket class as a private member of another class, the Connection class, like this:

```
class Connection{
   private:
     Socket socket;
     //more stuff
};
```

In the constructor of the `Connection` class I just want to pass as parameter one instance of `Socket` and assign it to the private member, like this:

```
Connection:Connection(Socket socket){
   this->socket = socket;
   //...
}
```

But the compiler asks me to call the `Socket` constructor inside the Connection constructor (or at least I think that); I'm getting this error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘Socket::Socket()’ 
>   Connection::Connection(Socket socket)

Which is the right way to do that (declaring the `Socket` outside and passing it as parameter in the `Connection` constructor)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calling constructor of a class member in constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761676/calling-constructor-of-a-class-member-in-constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens in the `Connection` constructor is that the `socket` member is first *default* constructed, as part of the object initialization. And you don't have a `Socket` default constructor (a constructor which takes no arguments).

*After* that, the body of the constructor is executed, and the *copy* assignment is made (to an already existing object).

You should use a *constructor initializer list* to construct/initialize the members:

```
Connection:Connection(Socket socket)
    : socket(socket)
{}
```

---

On a very related note: The `socket` object inside the `Connection` object is a *copy* of the actual `Socket` instance! What happens in the above initializer list is that the `socket` object is *copy-constructed*.

You should probably use *references* if you want to reference the original `Socket`:

```
class Connection
{
    ...
    Socket& socket;
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your clarifying answer. Do you know it is there any problem with using a copy of the Socket instead of the original? My Socket class works with UNIX socket system calls.

Comment: @pitazzo Not knowing what the `Socket` class does internally, I really can't say. It really depends on what you're doing, on the use-case.

Answer (score 2):

Use [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Explanation) instead, e.g.

```
Connection:Connection(Socket socket) : socket(socket) {}
```

> For members that cannot be default-initialized, such as members of reference and const-qualified types, member initializers must be specified.

For your approach, the data member `socket` has to be default initialized at first, then assigned in the constructor's body. But `Socket` doesn't have default constructor and can't be default initialized.

BTW: The default constructor won't be [implicitly generated](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Implicitly-declared_default_constructor) for `Socket` because it has user-provided constructors.

Answer (score 2):

You're actually assigning a new `Socket` to the *default constructed* `socket` member. And since there's no default constructor for `Socket` class, compiler gives you that error.

```
// Here, 'socket' is assigned to the default constructed 'this->socket'.
this->socket = socket;
```

To initialize/construct the `this->socket`, you should write it in the member initializer list:

```
Connection:Connection(Socket socket) : socket(socket) {
}
```

This way, `this->socket` is *copy constructed* from the given `socket`.

Answer (score 1):

Like said above, the data member socket is already default-constructed at the point the copy-assignment is called:

```
{
  // this->socket is already default-constructed here
  // but no default constructor Socket() available -> ERROR
  this->socket = socket;
}
```

That for the Socket constructor should be explicitely called, and that has to be within Connection constructor initliazer list (outside the constructor function body):

```
Connection::Connection(Socket sock) : socket(sock) {}
```

If you want a socket copy within your Connection class, you probably want to use

```
Connection::Connection(const Socket& sock)
```

instead of `Connection::Connection(Socket sock)`